# If Android is client, which one is faster to download a file from a PHP server? Get or Post request?

Tags: php, android

If Android is `client`
which one from the following items is faster to download a file from a `PHP server`?
1 - `HTTP Get request`
2 - `HTTP Post request` and receiving the data by `echo`

Comment: I do not see this as a duplicate of any of the two examples listed by @NileshRathod. Neither of those examples deal with response speed. I think this question has merit,

Comment: After defending this question as a possible duplicate, I would say that there are many factors invölved in determining whether there is a difference in response speed retrieving a file from a server (POST or GET). I would suggest that you preform your own test with the server available to you and make a decision based on your individual needs and server settings. Testing on my server could return gravely different results then your server.

Comment: This is one of those questions that looks silly at first, but a good answer could reveal a lot about the android platform and potentially web requests in general.

Comment: AFAIK, choosing between `GET/POST` request should not be done based on which one is faster(this is not often considered), it should be done based on your requirement like for example `GET` is mostly used to obtain data whereas `POST` can be used to create/modify data.

Comment: Your question does not make sense as a GET request can be handled by the webserver itself. Or by a php script invoked by the webserver.

Comment: Further you should have experimented with this yourself already and told us your findings.

Comment: Further you should have told us why you think it would make any difference for downloading a 10 MB file.